# How do I create custom headings?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, numbering

I'm using the document class `Thesis`, which is based on the more general class `book`. I would like to create a custom heading to specify specific sections of a mathematical model, e.g. `\modelsec{Zero Costs}`.

The section should have the same attributes as `\subsubsection` *except* that it is numbered A., B., and that it is centered. It should not appear in the Table of Contents.

I have been looking into different things for a while now, but I just don't have enough background to figure this out myself.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are zillions of `Thesis` classes around; can you point to a source for the one you're using?

Comment: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Answer (score 1):

A first attempt could be

```
\newcounter{modelsec}[subsection]
\renewcommand{\themodelsec}{\Alph{modelsec}}
\newcommand{\modelsec}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{modelsec}
  \subsubsection*{\centering\themodelsec. #1}%
}
```

We set up a new counter, that's reset at every `\subsection` command. Its representation is with uppercase letters. Then the `\modelsec` command is defined to step the counter and to issue `\subsubsection*` (so no number will be automatically added, but with centered heading and the special number is put before the title.

You can also set a `\label` for later reference:

```
\modelsec{Zero Costs}\label{ms:zero-costs}
```